# Sierra stuck at boot screen, upgrading to mojove will create new bootup files?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, high-sierra, startup

I am facing some issues in High Sierra . Since few days it's stuck at boot screen and load very slow, mac doesn't start even after completing the load progress bar. But when I charge it fully and after some time it start accidentally, and then after some time when i try to open it's not booting up.

Other problems are Command + R is not working on this OS and i am not able to recover when it's not booting up, even I tried netboot but globe was spinning and after completing the progress bar, it doesn't show any option instead apple logo appears again and then stuck at boot screen.

I am now going to upgrade High Sierra  to Mojave, I want to know if I am installing or upgrading to Mojave will it correct the bootup files and solve this issue and Command + R will work?

My os details :

```
MacOS High Sierra
Version : 10.13.4
MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017)
Processor 1.8 GHz intel Core i5
Memory 8 GB
```

Answer (score 1):

I also suggest better to upgrade and mostly it might fix your issue. Kindly use the following keyboard combination as per your requirements.

Basically, as per Apple Guidance:

**Command (⌘)-R** Install the latest macOS that was installed on your Mac.

**Option-⌘-R** Upgrade to the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac.

**Shift-Option-⌘-R** Install the macOS that came with your Mac, or the closest version still available.